# Symfony2 render form collection as ul

Tags: php, forms, symfony, render, twig

I got a big collection of forms which I would like to render this way:

```
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Form One</legend>
  <ul>
   <li><label>Label 1</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 2</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 3</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 4</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 5</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 6</label><input /></li>
  </ul>
 </fieldset>

 <fieldset>
  <legend>Form Two</legend>
  <ul>
   <li><label>Label 1</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 2</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 3</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 4</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 5</label><input /></li>
   <li><label>Label 6</label><input /></li>
  </ul>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

and so on.

I now tried hours to get this using form themes, I even played around with vendor/symfony/src/bridge/Twig/Ressources/view/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

But I don't success, twig always renders the subforms with li's instead of fieldset's and so on

Has someone any idea what I could do?

```
{% use "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}


{% block field_row %}
<li>
{{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
</li>    
{% endblock field_row %}


{% block form_errors %}
{% if errors|length > 0 %}
{{ block('field_errors') }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock form_errors %}


{% block field_errors %}
{% if errors|length > 0 %}
<ul>
{% for error in errors %}
<li>{{   error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators') }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock field_errors %}

{% block hidden_row %}
<b>{{ form_widget(form) }}</b>
{% endblock hidden_row %}


{% block form_widget %}
<ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
{{ block('field_rows') }}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
</ul>
{% endblock form_widget %}


{% block collection_widget %}
{% if prototype is defined %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype':     form_row(prototype) }) %}
{% endif %}
{{ block('form_widget') }}
{% endblock collection_widget %}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is localization of file with your widgets for form?

In your `config.yml` you should have

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    form:
        resources:
            - 'YourBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Or you can define your widgets in the same template with your form but before those widgets add

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```